# GitHub Pushing for read-only

Tags: git, github

I m new to Git so I am trying to learn git. Meanwhile When I am working on Git ,

> ERROR: Permission to username/file.git denied to Username1.
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I encountered this error. By the way , File is only readable. How can I push ?

- git clone git@github.com:username/file.git
- git add Files.txt
- git add .
- git commit -a -m "Second Commit"
- git push git@github.com:username/file.git

By the way git config

```
[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = true
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
ignorecase = true
precomposeunicode = false
[remote "origin"]
url = git@github.com:username/files.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
remote = origin
merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: Please show the steps you did.

Comment: git clone git@github.com:username/file.git
git add Files.txt
git add .
git commit -a -m "Second Commit"
git push git@github.com:username/file.git

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clone other one's repo and make some contributions to it, you need to fork the repo as your own first. Push commits to your own repo and you can send a "Pull Request" to the original author then.

```
git clone git@github.com:username/file.git
```

Here the `username` must be yours, or an org that you are in. Otherwise, you don't have the permission to update the repo.

---

B.t.w, a tip for you. You can

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:username/file.git
$ git push -u origin master
```

Since then you can push it simply by

```
$ git push
```